# Put a field as read-only with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to set a item to read only, as you see in the code i have tried several way and can't get that to work. Can anyone help me with this?

```
<html>
<script>

 //test.Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly")

 //document.getElementById('testtt').setAttribute('readonly', 'readOnly'); 

 // document.getElementByID('test').value=readOnly;

 //document.getElementByID('test').readOnly = true;

 // $("#test").attr("readonly", "readonly");

 //$("#test").removeAttr("readonly");

 //$('#test').attr('readonly', 'readonly');

 $("#test").attr("readonly")

</script>
<body>  
     <input id="test" type="text" value="text" />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This post could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306708/add-readonly-to-input-jquery/1306723#1306723

Comment: Tanks all for the fast reply i get it to works. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#test').attr('readonly', true);
```

working example : http://jsfiddle.net/FBUDt/

Answer (score 1):

this should work for you:

```
 $("#test").attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

remember that the DOM needs to be loaded before you try to find the element

you could use jquerys DOM-ready

```
$(function() {
    $("#test").attr("readonly", "readonly");
});
```

what version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You should try wrapping your code into `$('document').ready();`

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/),

> The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.

So it would be:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $("#test").attr("readonly", "readonly");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to an element that is created later in the document. Move the script down below the form, or place it in a document.ready block. Also, you should use [`$.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) in jQuery 1.6+

```
$(function(){
  $('#test').prop('readonly', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with

```
document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('readonly', 'readOnly');
```

**But that is not the issue**. The position of your script is where it goes wrong. You are trying to change element which does not exist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <meta charset=utf-8 />
     <title>testcase</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="some container">
      <input id="test" type="text" value="text" />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
       document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('readonly', 'readOnly');
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you place your scripts right befor the closing `</body>` tag , then it is executes as soon as DOM has been built.

And please. Stop using JS libraries to do the most basic things.

Comment: Since `setAttribute()` is 'monumentally broken' in IE<8 (Source: http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/setAttribute#compatibilitysection), using jQuery for this is perfectly sound.

Comment: @Jens Roland how th hell can you defend adding a 20KB bloat for setting single attribute? There is an issue in IE .. no problem .. check for it. Or set value to `document.getElementByID('test').readOnly` instead. But do not promote using huge JS libraries because of ignorance.

Comment: Haha.... Of course I wouldn't defend that. I assume he's using jQuery already and for a lot more, or he wouldn't tag the question 'jQuery'

Comment: @Jens Roland always expect worst possible situation.

Comment: @jens that was what I and (almost) everyone probably have assumed too

Answer (score 0):

you are missing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
});
```

sample

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pe4J5/