# disable textbox by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to disable textbox using jquery:

```
$('#<%=txtFrom.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', true);
```

It looks as disabled: [image], but actually it's not, I can write there. Why?

**UPDATE:** Fixed by adding input in the code:

```
$('#<%=txtFrom.ClientID %> input').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: If what you want is just read only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306708/add-readonly-to-input-jquery

Comment: Seems to [**work**](http://jsfiddle.net/vzGHm/) for me, but `prop()` is actually the preferred method, and did you remember document.ready ?

Comment: Of course, I used after document.ready, actually after Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded.

Comment: Mario, you mean I should use ReadOnly instead disabled? Disabled worked for me before.

Comment: added input, it looks it's working: $('#<%=txtFrom.ClientID %> input').attr('disabled', true);

Comment: Sounds like your jQuery selector was wrong, punch `$('#<%=txtFrom.ClientID %>)` into the browser console debug window and see what you get.

Comment: Now it's working fine after I added input. So I think problem is resolved, although I don't know exactly what input means and why I need it. Anyway thank you for help.

Comment: Snixtor, maybe you're right, txtFrom is id from ASP.NET, so txtFrom.ClientID should give client id. But anyway, it's working now and I just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do that:

```
$('#YOUR_ELEMENT_ID').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: Why? If it works with true and false? I prefer to use boolean value, because actually I use some condition to enable and disable it.