# Set Readonly for Multiple textbox onclick

Tags: php, javascript

I am coding in PHP. I have a table containing 'x' number of Textboxes. 'x' varies.

I want the textboxes initially readOnly. But when I click on a textbox, it should be editable.

I can write the code for fixed number of textboxes. But I want to know how it is done for variabe number.

My sample code:

```
<form>
<?php 
for($i=0;$i<$x;$i++)
{
   echo("<input name='fe_text[]' type='text' readonly /><br/>");
}
 ?>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Why make them read-only when you intend to make them editable anyway? I don't get your logic.

Comment: I don't understand why, but add ` onclick="this.readOnly=false;"` to the `<input`s

Comment: You could just style the textboxes to look readonly.

Comment: Use jQuery, to toggle the readonly on/off http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306708/add-readonly-to-input-jquery

Comment: What problem is it that you're trying to solve; as Madara implies: this makes no sense. *Why* do they need to be `readonly` until someone clicks them? Please, read the following: '[what is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)' for reference.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('body').on('click', 'input[type=text]', function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('readonly');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little trickery with onclick event:

```
echo("<input name='fe_text[]' type='text' readonly onclick="this.readOnly=false" /><br/>");
```

or you can use jQuery events

```
$('#input-container').on('click', 'input' function()
{
   $(this).prop('readonly', false);
});
```