# jquery cannot be disabled from server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have some little problem with jQuery, I want to disable this jQuery, I've tried anything to do it like I disable use tag DIV, and PANEL from server side but not working, this is my jQuery I want to disable:

```
//To show or hide button select
 $("[ID*=DivText]").click(function() {
  $(this).next("[ID*=DivImgSelect]").css("display", "block");
  $(this).prevAll("[ID*=hdnFooter]").val("True");
  $(this).prevAll("[ID*=hdnText]").val("True");
  $(this).css("display", "none");
  });
  $("[ID*=DivImgSelect]").click(function() {
  $(this).prevAll("[ID*=DivText]").css("display", "block");
  $(this).prevAll("[ID*=hdnFooter]").val("False");
  $(this).prevAll("[ID*=hdnText]").val("False");
  $(this).css("display", "none");
   });
```

and this is my tag asp while used jquery:

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Panel ID="DisplayFlags" runat="server" Enabled ="true">
 <div id="DivTextInbox" runat="server" class="outerDiv" style='<%#  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InboxFlag").ToString()=="True" ? "display:none": "display:block" %>'>
<a class="LinkText">
    <asp:Label ID="spanLinkInbox" CssClass="LinkText" Style="cursor: pointer" ForeColor="blue" runat="server" Text="Not Allowed "></asp:Label></a>
</div>
<div id="DivImgSelectInbox" runat="server"  class="imageSelected" style='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InboxFlag").ToString()=="True" ? "display:block": "display:none" %>'>
                                                                       <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgSelectInbox" ImageUrl="~/Images/check.png" Width="16px"
                                                                        Style="cursor: pointer" />
                                                                  </div>
                                                                  </asp:Panel>
                                                                </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Disable?? Why don't you just remove the code?
Yr question is not clear btw..

Comment: remove the code ? that code I used, when in Condition enable I Used that, otherwise when disable condition i'm not use that,,, i hope it's clearly

Comment: @user3606622 u can use ReadOnly or u can remove the clickevent of `DivImgSelect` as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1306723/2763709 this is the simplest one

Comment: @TheDictator nah, how I can remove the clickevent of divImgselect on server side ? because I don't know dude ?

Comment: why didnt u tag this Question with aSp.nEt?

Comment: ok I'm Sorry @PratikJoshi

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just make use of this below code i guess u'll get the answer

```
$("[ID*=DivImgSelect]").off('click');
```

to use it backend side just use as below..

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", 
         "<script type='text/javascript'>$('[ID*=DivImgSelect]').off('click');
                                                            </script>", false);
```

Comment: hmm,, how I implemented the code to the server side ? can help me dude @TheDictator

Comment: :)) u did the same thing with me dictator

Comment: see the updated answer... and u can use bind()/unbind() as well which is also there as an answer given below...

Comment: @sakir bro he dont know that thats why i needed to update my answer.. and thats the only way he can pply that...

Answer (score 2):

I didnt try it but

you can unbind event like this from client side

```
$( "#foo" ).unbind();
```

but I guess u wanna do that from server side then register this script

something like this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>youcode here</script>", false);
```

Comment: so my JQuery code put on  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>youcode here</script>", false);
isn't it ?

Comment: He has clearly mentioned that `youcode here` .. now u just need to put your code there