# Accessing text boxes and dropdown list of each row in asp.net GridView separately

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view as below

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid_flats_allflatslist" OnRowDeleting="grid_flats_allflatslist_RowDeleting" runat="server" Width="95%" CssClass="gridview" ShowFooter="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="8" BackColor="Black" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" frame="below" DataKeyNames="BlockID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BlockID" HeaderText="Block ID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BlockName" HeaderText="Block Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Flat Number">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="text_flats_listflatnumber" CssClass="textbox" onkeypress="return numeric(this);" MaxLength="5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Flat Number">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="list_flats_listflattype" CssClass="droplist" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="list_flats_listflattype_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Bachelor" Value="Bachelor"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Family" Value="Family"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Max Vacancy">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="text_flats_listmaxvacancy" onkeypress="return numeric(this);" MaxLength="2" CssClass="textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="Delete" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#9e4900" ForeColor="#fff1e5" Font-Bold="false" Font-Underline="false" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#9e4900" ForeColor="#fff1e5" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#ff8080" ForeColor="#660000" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#ffe7d6" ForeColor="#660000" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#ffd6ba" ForeColor="#660000" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#fff9f4" HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="Black" />
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="button_flats_flatplus" CssClass="button" Height="30px" Width="25%" runat="server" Text="Add Flat" OnClick="button_flats_flatplus_Click" />
```

Initially, this is empty and when I click on the `button_flats_flatsplus` button then a row will be added to the grid view with the field as above. It will also have 2 text boxes and a drop-down list. The button click event is as below.

```
protected void button_flats_flatplus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt;
    DataRow dr = null;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] == null)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BlockID", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BlockName", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["BlockID"] = list_flats_blocklist.SelectedValue; // I get this value from a different list
        dr["BlockName"] = list_flats_blocklist.SelectedItem.Text; // I get this value from a different list
        dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
        grid_flats_allflatslist.DataSource = dt;
        grid_flats_allflatslist.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        dt = (DataTable) ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["BlockID"] = list_flats_blocklist.SelectedValue; // I get this value from a different list
        dr["BlockName"] = list_flats_blocklist.SelectedItem.Text; // I get this value from a different list
        dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
        grid_flats_allflatslist.DataSource = dt;
        grid_flats_allflatslist.DataBind();
    }
}
```

After I add many rows the grid view will look as below,

[image: My GridView]

If I press delete here then it is getting deleted successfully. Now I will enter the values in text boxes. But when I select on `Family` from row 1 then the `Max Vacancy` text box of row 1 should be disabled and text content is made to `--`. If I select `Bachelor` from row 1 then the `Max Vacancy` text box from row 1 should be enabled and text cleared to me to enter a value. The same should be done for whatever row I work on. But I am not sure how I can do this because I only have one ID for the textbox within the grid view and I am not sure how to access each row elements separately.

After entering all the values I will click on a save button and that should insert all values in entered into database row by row as in grid view. This also I'm not sure how to do because I can't access each row textbox separately. Is there any way I can do this?

My row deleting code is as below,

```
protected void grid_flats_allflatslist_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
    DataTable dt = ViewState["CurrentTable"] as DataTable;
    dt.Rows[index].Delete();
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
    grid_flats_allflatslist.DataSource = dt;
    grid_flats_allflatslist.DataBind();
}
```

The first bound field of the grid view `BlockID` should be the primary key when inserting the values into the database. For good visibility, I have made that hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to add validation for Flat Number and Max Vacancy

```
$(document).on('change', '.droplist', function(){
     var parentRow=$(this).parents("tr:eq(0)");
     var text_flats_listmaxvacancy=$(parentRow).find('[id*="text_flats_listmaxvacancy"]');

     var _value=$(this).val();
     if(_value=="Family"){
         $(text_flats_listmaxvacancy).val("--");             
         $(text_flats_listmaxvacancy).attr("readonly",true);
     }
     else if(_value=="Bachelor"){
         $(text_flats_listmaxvacancy).val("");
         $(text_flats_listmaxvacancy).attr("readonly",false);
     }
});

//Code for save button to find each row and controls
foreach(GridViewRow row in grid_flats_allflatslist.Rows)
{
    TextBox text_flats_listflatnumber=(TextBox)row.FindControl("text_flats_listflatnumber"); 
    DropDownList list_flats_listflattype=(DropDownList)row.FindControl("list_flats_listflattype");
    TextBox text_flats_listmaxvacancy=(TextBox)row.FindControl("text_flats_listmaxvacancy");
}
```

Remove `AutoPostBack` and `OnSelectedIndexChanged` from the drop-down list and make it as below,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="list_flats_listflattype" CssClass="droplist" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Bachelor" Value="Bachelor"></asp:ListItem
    <asp:ListItem Text="Family" Value="Family"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Nice, The text `--` is getting changed when I click family and it clear when I select bachelor. But the enabled and disabled is not happening

Comment: I have updated code and add readonly attribute. Try with this if it works.

Comment: No still not working, same as before enabled/disabled not working

Comment: Try this `$('#text_flats_listmaxvacancy').attr('readonly', true);`
Insted of this `$(text_flats_listmaxvacancy).attr("readonly","readonly");`

Comment: And `false` in the else block. @ManoPrathibhanC

Comment: @ManoPrathibhanC Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: im using the 1.4.1 version..readonly true and false is also not working

Comment: You can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306708/add-readonly-to-input-jquery

Comment: Ok now it's working :) I removed the `AutoPostBack` and `OnSelectedIndexChanged` from the drop-down list and now its working. Thank you

Comment: In case i want to use `RequiredFieldValidator` for all the text boxes in the grid view when i click on final submit to save to database, how can i do that?

Comment: You can refer this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-ASPNet-RequiredFieldValidator-for-TextBox-inside-GridView-TemplateField-ItemTemplate.aspx