# How to set textbox as read only when editing and enable it when adding new ID in HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

If I use the below code, will it disable the textbox even if I am inserting a new record?

```
<input id="code" data-bind="value: Code" name="Code" type="text" placeholder="Your Code" class="form-control input-md" readonly>
```

Comment: You should provide more details and code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in jQuery using **.prop()** method.

`$('input').prop('readonly', true)` to disable the textbox or `$('input').prop('readonly', false)` to re-enable the textbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to change attribute of a control

```
$("#code").attr("readonly", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery <1.9

```
$('#inputId').attr('readonly', true);
```

jQuery 1.9+

```
$('#inputId').prop('readonly', true);
```

[Add "readonly" to <input > (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306708/add-readonly-to-input-jquery)