# Form input field read-only - no autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with a form set up for Autocomplete. The field below must not be overwritten.

```
<dl>
  <dt>
    <label for="ctl00_bc_custom_element_43">Vareinfo</label>
  </dt>
  <dd>
    <input name="ctl00$bc$custom_element_43" type="text" id="ctl00_bc_custom_element_43" />
  </dd>
</dl>
```

I have tried to remove autocomplete via javascript, but it does not seem to work - can you possibly insert 'Read only' specifically in this field

Comment: How are you adding autocomplete functionality to this field?

Comment: It is a webshop where it is automatically made in this way, at all shops. Not possible to access the form code directly.

Comment: What webshop software are you using? This is important information which should be in the question

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306708/how-to-add-a-readonly-attribute-to-an-input